# How to automate an IE webapp that pops a modal HTML dialog?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, browser-automation, iwebbrowser2

[**Revised yet again** for clarity]

I have a C++ program which interacts with a website. The site is IE-specific, and so is my program.

I'm connecting to the running instance of IE in an ordinary way (*out of process* -- see code). Once I get the `IWebBrowser2`, I have no problem getting the `IHTMLDocument2` and interacting with the individual `IHTMLElement` objects, filling in fields and clicking buttons.

But if the web page has javascript that calls [window.showModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I'm stuck: I need to interact with the HTML elements in the popup, just like the other pages; but I can't seem to get its `IWebBrowser2`.

The popup is always titled "Web Page Dialog", and is a window of type `Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame` containing an `Internet Explorer_Server`. But I can't get the IWebBrowser2 from the `Internet Explorer_Server` window the way I can when it's a normal IE instance.

I can get the `IHTMLDocument2Ptr`, but when I try to get the `IWebBrowser2` I get an `HRESULT` of `E_NOINTERFACE`.

The code is pretty standard stuff, and works fine if it's a 'normal' IE window

```
IHTMLDocument2Ptr pDoc;
LRESULT lRes;

/* hWndChild is an instance of class "Internet Explorer_Server" */

UINT nMsg = ::RegisterWindowMessage( "WM_HTML_GETOBJECT" );
::SendMessageTimeout( hWndChild, nMsg, 0L, 0L, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, 
    (DWORD*)&lRes );

LPFNOBJECTFROMLRESULT pfObjectFromLresult = 
    (LPFNOBJECTFROMLRESULT)::GetProcAddress( hInst, "ObjectFromLresult" );
if ( pfObjectFromLresult != NULL )
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = (*pfObjectFromLresult)( lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, (void**)&pDoc );
    if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) ) {
        IServiceProvider *pService;
        hr = pDoc->QueryInterface(IID_IServiceProvider, (void **) &pService);
        if ( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            hr = pService->QueryService(SID_SWebBrowserApp,
                IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **) &pBrowser);

            // This is where the problem occurs:
            // hr == E_NOINTERFACE
         }
    }
}
```

In case it matters, this is **Vista** and **IE8**. (I emphasize this because both of these introduced breaking changes in my codebase, which had worked fine with XP/IE7.)

Once again, my goal is to get each `IHTMLElement` and interact with it. I don't have access to the source code of the application which I'm automating.

I'm considering sending keystrokes blindly to the `Internet Explorer_Server` window, but would rather not.

**Edited to add:**

Someone suggested getting the child windows and sending them messages, but I'm pretty sure that doesn't work with `Internet Explorer_Server`; according to Spy++, there's aren't any child windows. (This is not IE-specific. Java applets don't seem to have child windows, either.)

**Update**

In the comments, Simon Maurer said the above code worked for him, and just to make sure there were no typos he very generously posted a complete standalone app on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uj1nXG4S). When I used his code, it failed in the same way in the same place, and I realized he thought I wanted to connect to the **underlying** page, not the popup. So I've edited the text above to remove that ambiguity.

Comment: What's the exception?  Does `pDoc` look valid when you call `pDoc->QueryInterface`?

Comment: @NateHekman : I've substantially revised the question.

Comment: Can you confirm the c++ app is out-of-process? What's a "webpage dialog"? Is it the IE window that pops up when a script calls showModalDialog?

Comment: @SimonMourier - I've revised the question. **Yes**, it's definitely out of process. (An earlier version of the app worked in-process, but that stopped working with IE8.) **Yes**, I assume the app is calling showModalDialog.

Comment: FYI, I have tested this code with IE 10 on Windows 8 and it works, even with a modal dialog displayed.

Comment: @SimonMourier - Just to make sure: you mean you've tested *my* code with IE10, yes? (I haven't - the customer uses IE8.)

Comment: In fact, I also tested this on IE8, Windows 7. My code is here http://pastebin.com/uj1nXG4S and the HTML file used is simply this `<html><input type="button" onclick="window.showModalDialog('test.htm');" /></html>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you want to get the `IServiceProvider` or `IWebBrowser2` if you just want the `IHTMLElement`'s. You can get them by calling the `IHTMLDocument`'s `get_all()` method.

This code snippet shows you how this works:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mshtml.h>
#include <Exdisp.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <SHLGUID.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <tchar.h>

HRESULT EnumElements(HINSTANCE hOleAccInst, HWND child)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    UINT nMsg = ::RegisterWindowMessage(_T("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT"));
    LRESULT lRes = 0;
    ::SendMessageTimeout(child, nMsg, 0L, 0L, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, (PDWORD)&lRes);

    LPFNOBJECTFROMLRESULT pfObjectFromLresult = (LPFNOBJECTFROMLRESULT)::GetProcAddress(hOleAccInst, "ObjectFromLresult");
    if (pfObjectFromLresult == NULL)
        return S_FALSE;

    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spDoc;
    hr = (*pfObjectFromLresult)(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument2, 0, (void**)&spDoc);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    CComPtr<IHTMLElementCollection> spElementCollection;
    hr = spDoc->get_all(&spElementCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    CComBSTR url;
    spDoc->get_URL(&url);
    printf("URL: %ws\n", url);

    long lElementCount;
    hr = spElementCollection->get_length(&lElementCount);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    printf("Number of elements: %d", lElementCount);

    VARIANT vIndex; vIndex.vt = VT_I4;
    VARIANT vSubIndex; vSubIndex.vt = VT_I4; vSubIndex.lVal = 0;
    for (vIndex.lVal = 0; vIndex.lVal < lElementCount; vIndex.lVal++)
    {
        CComPtr<IDispatch> spDispatchElement;
        if (FAILED(spElementCollection->item(vIndex, vSubIndex, &spDispatchElement)))
            continue;
        CComPtr<IHTMLElement> spElement;
        if (FAILED(spDispatchElement->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLElement, (void**)&spElement)))
            continue;
        CComBSTR tagName;
        if (SUCCEEDED(spElement->get_tagName(&tagName)))
        {
            printf("%ws\n", tagName);
        }
    }
    return S_OK;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    HINSTANCE hInst = ::LoadLibrary(_T("OLEACC.DLL"));
    if (hInst != NULL)
    {
        HRESULT hr = EnumElements(hInst, (HWND)0x000F05E4);    // Handle to Internet Explorer_Server determined with Spy++ :)
        ::FreeLibrary(hInst);
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Above code works on both: a normal window or a modal window, just pass the correct `HWND` to the `SendMessageTimeout` function.

**WARNING** I use a hard-coded `HWND` value in this example, if you want to test it you should start an IE instance and get the `HWND` of the `Internet Explorer_Server` window using Spy++.

I also advise you to use [`CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ezzw7k98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: I'll try this. What version(s) of IE are you using?

Comment: **YES** this seems to work! It's true that in this application I only need the  `spElement`, from there I can derive everything else.